# Cant compile Netbeans generated .java files into .class on command line

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line, compilation

I built my java program as part of a uni assignment and as part of the submission it has to be able to be compiled and run in a DOS window (read Windows command window). The program runs fine in Netbeans but when I copy over all the .java files to a separate folder and try and compile each one I get a huge number of compilation errors. When I created the files in Netbeans, I made them all part of the one package and let Netbeans add a "package *Project_Name*" to the top of each class. The rest is standard java, nothing too complex. ITs my first time using Netbeans (version 7.1.1 is what Im using) and its driving me crazy. I can create a .jar file and I can run that from the command line but I need to be able to show that the source code can be compiled from the command line, and the resulting file(s) can also be run form the command line. Has anyone else had this problem, and if so, how did you overcome it or does anyone know what to do to sort this problem out.

I have a feeling its to do with references to other files as most of the errors are related to objects that are created and methods that are invoked from other files. fOr exmaple, I have a Manager.java file that has constructors and methods for a Manager object and then in another file (say Proprety.java) I have code to create a Manager object using the new keyword.

The current CLASSPATH Im using is

CLASSPATH = .;C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_03\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;

The PATH variable is set up like

...;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin

And thats it. The only libraries Im using are java.util.* and java.io.* All other references are to the class files I created in Netbeans

Any help would really be appreicated.

Results of SET command:

```
C:\>set
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
APPDATA=C:\Users\Gunit\AppData\Roaming
asl.log=Destination=file
CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_03\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib
\ext\QTJava.zip;C:\Estateman
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=GUNIT-PC
ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\Gunit
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Gunit\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\GUNIT-PC
MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH=C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=2
OS=Windows_NT
Path=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\syst
em32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v
1.0\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Acronis\SnapAPI\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft S
QL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:
\Program Files\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Progr
am Files\Common Files\Avid;Avid;C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;C:\Program Files\Co
mmon Files\Adobe\AGL;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;C:\Program Files\Java
\jre7\bin
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 15 Model 6 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=15
PROCESSOR_REVISION=0605
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
QTJAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
SESSIONNAME=Console
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\Windows
TEMP=C:\Users\Gunit\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\Gunit\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN=Gunit-PC
USERNAME=Gunit
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Gunit
VS100COMNTOOLS=c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\
windir=C:\Windows
```

Command Im running:

```
C:\Estateman>javac Manager.java
```

Output:

```
Manager.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
        Property temp0 = new Rental(24,"Bogan Ave","Geelong",3040,"Bob Jones
","0420685765","Victoria","Tues 8am",280.50,"23/4/2012");
        ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
        Property temp0 = new Rental(24,"Bogan Ave","Geelong",3040,"Bob Jones
","0420685765","Victoria","Tues 8am",280.50,"23/4/2012");
                             ^
symbol:   class Rental
location: class Manager
Manager.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
        Property temp1 = new Selling(56,"Maritime Rd","Perth",6000,"Alan Gib
s","0400345964","Perth","Wed 3pm",350485.00);
        ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
        Property temp1 = new Selling(56,"Maritime Rd","Perth",6000,"Alan Gib
s","0400345964","Perth","Wed 3pm",350485.00);
                             ^
symbol:   class Selling
location: class Manager
Manager.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
        Property temp2 = new Selling(901,"Preston Rd","Murdoch",6505,"Alan G
ibs","0400345964","Perth","Fri 10am",890000.00);
        ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
        Property temp2 = new Selling(901,"Preston Rd","Murdoch",6505,"Alan G
ibs","0400345964","Perth","Fri 10am",890000.00);
                             ^
symbol:   class Selling
location: class Manager
Manager.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
        Property temp3 = new Rental(83,"Joke Way","Murdoch",6505,"Grace Kell
y","0123493436","Winthrop","Fri 1pm",475.00,"18/4/2012");
        ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
        Property temp3 = new Rental(83,"Joke Way","Murdoch",6505,"Grace Kell
y","0123493436","Winthrop","Fri 1pm",475.00,"18/4/2012");
                             ^
symbol:   class Rental
location: class Manager
Manager.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
        Property temp4 = new Selling(167,"Joke Way","Murdoch",6505,"Bob Jone
s","0420685765","Victoria","Sat 3pm","17/5/2012");
        ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
        Property temp4 = new Selling(167,"Joke Way","Murdoch",6505,"Bob Jone
s","0420685765","Victoria","Sat 3pm","17/5/2012");
                             ^
symbol:   class Selling
location: class Manager
Manager.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
        Property temp5 = new Selling(2,"Ashbury Lane","Success",6110,"Ian Fi
elder","0895484453","Atwell","Mon 11am",900000.00);
        ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
        Property temp5 = new Selling(2,"Ashbury Lane","Success",6110,"Ian Fi
elder","0895484453","Atwell","Mon 11am",900000.00);
                             ^
symbol:   class Selling
location: class Manager
Manager.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
        Utils u = new Utils();
        ^
symbol:   class Utils
location: class Manager
Manager.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
        Utils u = new Utils();
                      ^
symbol:   class Utils
location: class Manager
Manager.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
            Property temp = new Selling(num,name,sub,code,person,phone,offic
e,open,price);
            ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
            Property temp = new Selling(num,name,sub,code,person,phone,offic
e,open,price);
                                ^
symbol:   class Selling
location: class Manager
Manager.java:92: error: cannot find symbol
                Property temp = new Rental(num,name,sub,code,person,phone,of
fice,open,price,vacant);
                ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:92: error: cannot find symbol
                Property temp = new Rental(num,name,sub,code,person,phone,of
fice,open,price,vacant);
                                    ^
symbol:   class Rental
location: class Manager
Manager.java:156: error: cannot find symbol
            Property temp = (Property)(itr.next());
            ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:156: error: cannot find symbol
            Property temp = (Property)(itr.next());
                             ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:165: error: cannot find symbol
                    Rental rTemp = (Rental)(temp);
                    ^
symbol:   class Rental
location: class Manager
Manager.java:165: error: cannot find symbol
                    Rental rTemp = (Rental)(temp);
                                    ^
symbol:   class Rental
location: class Manager
Manager.java:173: error: cannot find symbol
                    Selling sTemp = (Selling)(temp);
                    ^
symbol:   class Selling
location: class Manager
Manager.java:173: error: cannot find symbol
                    Selling sTemp = (Selling)(temp);
                                     ^
symbol:   class Selling
location: class Manager
Manager.java:180: error: cannot find symbol
                    Selling sTemp = (Selling)(temp);
                    ^
symbol:   class Selling
location: class Manager
Manager.java:180: error: cannot find symbol
                    Selling sTemp = (Selling)(temp);
                                     ^
symbol:   class Selling
location: class Manager
Manager.java:198: error: cannot find symbol
        Utils u = new Utils();
        ^
symbol:   class Utils
location: class Manager
Manager.java:198: error: cannot find symbol
        Utils u = new Utils();
                      ^
symbol:   class Utils
location: class Manager
Manager.java:199: error: cannot find symbol
        Property tmp = new Property();
        ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:199: error: cannot find symbol
        Property tmp = new Property();
                           ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:212: error: cannot find symbol
            Property temp = (Property)(itr.next());
            ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:212: error: cannot find symbol
            Property temp = (Property)(itr.next());
                             ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:238: error: cannot find symbol
        Property temp = new Property();
        ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:238: error: cannot find symbol
        Property temp = new Property();
                            ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:239: error: cannot find symbol
        Utils u = new Utils();
        ^
symbol:   class Utils
location: class Manager
Manager.java:239: error: cannot find symbol
        Utils u = new Utils();
                      ^
symbol:   class Utils
location: class Manager
Manager.java:249: error: cannot find symbol
        ((Property)(properties.get(i))).address.setStreetNum(num);
          ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:250: error: cannot find symbol
        ((Property)(properties.get(i))).address.setStreetName(name);
          ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:251: error: cannot find symbol
        ((Property)(properties.get(i))).address.setSuburb(sub);
          ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:252: error: cannot find symbol
        ((Property)(properties.get(i))).address.setPostCode(code);
          ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:266: error: cannot find symbol
        Utils u = new Utils();
        ^
symbol:   class Utils
location: class Manager
Manager.java:266: error: cannot find symbol
        Utils u = new Utils();
                      ^
symbol:   class Utils
location: class Manager
Manager.java:273: error: cannot find symbol
        Property temp = new Property();
        ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:273: error: cannot find symbol
        Property temp = new Property();
                            ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:280: error: cannot find symbol
        ((Property)(properties.get(i))).contact.setContact(name,phone,office
);
          ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:296: error: cannot find symbol
            Property temp = (Property)(itr.next());
            ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:296: error: cannot find symbol
            Property temp = (Property)(itr.next());
                             ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:311: error: cannot find symbol
        Utils u = new Utils();
        ^
symbol:   class Utils
location: class Manager
Manager.java:311: error: cannot find symbol
        Utils u = new Utils();
                      ^
symbol:   class Utils
location: class Manager
Manager.java:317: error: cannot find symbol
        Property temp = new Property();
        ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:317: error: cannot find symbol
        Property temp = new Property();
                            ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:320: error: cannot find symbol
        ((Property)(properties.get(i))).viewing.setTime(time);
          ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:332: error: cannot find symbol
        Utils u = new Utils();
        ^
symbol:   class Utils
location: class Manager
Manager.java:332: error: cannot find symbol
        Utils u = new Utils();
                      ^
symbol:   class Utils
location: class Manager
Manager.java:341: error: cannot find symbol
            Property temp = (Property)(itr.next());
            ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
Manager.java:341: error: cannot find symbol
            Property temp = (Property)(itr.next());
                             ^
symbol:   class Property
location: class Manager
57 errors

C:\Estateman>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you setting an appropriate classpath? You don't really provide any actual information we can use to help.

Comment: You should include some basic information about the used classes. Do you set the proper classpath? Do you use libraries?

Comment: THe files I am trying to compile are located in C:\Estateman

Comment: The libraries I am using are java.util and java.io.  The rest are the classes I have created myself

Comment: It might help if you posted the command you are running and the output you get.

Comment: Command at prompt:  C:\Estateman> javac Manager.java

Comment: Output:  A very lengthy steament of Java complaining that of "Cant find symbol".  Thats the output for almost every error.  All other commands are the same as listed above (javac filename.java) and almost all come back with errors.  I have managed to get 2 of the 9 files to compile but thats it

Comment: The files I am trying to compile are located in C:\Estateman 

Ive tried searching for the classpath statements to configure java properly.  I downloaded Netbeans and installed it and let hte installer take care of everything - now Im finding out that it was a big mistake.

Please, anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: For future reference, edit the original post, do *not* create a new post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think, the key here is:

> I made them all part of the one package and let Netbeans add a "package *Project_Name*" to the top of each class.

And your command to compile:

> `javac Manager.java`

Assuming your package name is `projectname`. Then Netbeans created a directory `projectname` and placed all your Java files `Manager.java`, `Property.java`, and so on in it.

In Java the package structure corresponds directly to the directory structure in your file system. E.g. if you have a class `A` in package `x.y.z` then the source code file for class `A` is in file `x\y\z\A.java`.

So when you copy all your `*.java` files you have to ensure to also copy the original directory structure. In your case you can copy your classes `Manager.java`, `Property.java`, ... to `C:\test\projectname`. Then in your DOS box `cd` to this directory and compile your classes with:

```
javac -cp .. Manager.java
```

The meaning of the `-cp ..` command line option is, that the root of your package/directory structure is one level up at `C:\test`. Then while compiling `Manager.java` the Java compiler finds the reference to class `Property` and it assumes that class `Property` is in the same package as class `Manager`. So the compiler is looking for  class `projectname.Property`. With the `-cp` option pointing to `C:\ţest`, the compiler knows it should look into directory `C:\test\projectname`.

After compiling you can run your program with:

```
java -cp .. projectname.Manager
```